# In the last scene of the movie "A Clockwork Orange" By Stanley Kubrick

Tags: analysis, a-clockwork-orange

In the last scene of the  movie "A Clockwork Orange" By Stanley Kubrick,

> *Fred*: Do you understand, Alex? Have I made myself clear?
>
> *Alex*: As an unmuddied lake, Fred. As clear as an azure sky of deepest
>   summer. You can rely on me, Fred.

I just want to know why the word deepest is used to denote summer? generally summer is hot, may be the question is on use of word in proper sense related. I shall be happy if someone just make me understand that why  the word deepest is used  to signify summer. I am not good in English!

Comment: I think the question will be better suited and comprehensively answered on [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this context, the phrase "of deepest summer" means something like "in the middle of summer"... in other words, a time when the weather is as summery as possible, and as far as possible from the other seasons.